# Put apex:pageBlockSectionItem into apex:component

Tags: visualforce-component

I have a few apex:pageBlockSectionItem

```
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem helpText="{!$ObjectType.Opportunity.fields.TextField__c.InlineHelpText}"
      dataStyleClass="myCSS" labelStyleClass="myCSS"
    >
      <apex:outputLabel value="{!$ObjectType.Opportunity.fields.TextField__c.Label}"/>
      <apex:inputField value="{!opp.TextField__c}" taborderhint="2" styleClass="myCSS" />
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

on my page. They are identical, with exception of helpText attribute, inputField value and taborderhint.
I was looking to put this code into an apex:component, but I stuck with apex:inputField tag. How can I put field in it? Fields have different types.

Comment: Maybe there is a way to pass an object as first attribute and name of field as second attribute. Then using some inline functions get object's value, basing on field name/

Answer (score 0):

You can use fieldsets for your work .

Based on requirements you will pass different fieldsets

Sample code

```
   <apex:component Controller="Controller">
 <!-- These attributes are REQUIRED -->
 <apex:attribute type="String" name="sobj" required="true" description="Original poster failed to provide a useful description"/>
<apex:attribute type="String" name="fieldsetName" required="true" description="Original poster failed to provide a useful description"/>

<!-- This is the Markup of the actual component. -->
<!-- An apex:repeat tag iterates over the collection specified by the value attribute
    For each iteration it provides a local variable whose name you assign with the
    var attribute. So, for example: we'll iterate over the records returned
    by our query, and then for a given record, we'll iterate over
    the fields in the fieldsets. -->

 <!-- iterate over each of the records in the records collection -->
<apex:repeat var="record" value="{!records}">
<!-- iterate over each of the fields in the fieldset -->
<apex:repeat var="field" value="{!fieldsets}"> 
    <!-- for this iteration's record and for this field in the fieldset
                create an outputText field. -->
    <apex:inputfield value="{!record[field]}" />
</apex:repeat>
```

```
/The Controller will look like this:
   public with sharing class controller {


  // Can't use property syntax for component attributes so here's setters:
     public string sobj;
     public string fieldsetName;

   public void setSobj(string incomingSobj){
     this.sobj = incomingsObj;
  }

public void setFieldsetName(string incomingFieldsetName){
   this.fieldsetName = incomingFieldsetName;
}

  public controller(){

  }

  public List<Schema.FieldSetMember> getFields() {
        Schema.SObjectType t = Type.forName(this.sobj).getSObjectType();
      return t.contact.fieldSets.get(this.fieldsetName).getFields();
  }

}
```

Comment: The reason to do this refactoring is get rid of a lot of code. Your solution brings addition pain - controller.

Comment: I dont see without writing code you would be able to optimize it ..